how do you use filter & select together in microsoft graph api
this works
let get_user_url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta/?$filter= id eq '0cc55ffa-cf60-1e21-019c-10a272dd6bbc'

i need - to get delta from a group and get certain fields
let get_user_url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta/?$filter= id eq '0cc55ffa-cf60-1e21-019c-10a272dd6bbc'&$ select=id,displayName,mail,userPrincipalName`;

or
let get_user_url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta/?$filter= id eq '0cc55ffa-cf60-1e21-019c-10a272dd6bbc' and $select=id,displayName,mail,userPrincipalName`;

none of the two expressions  are  working. any suggestions on how this can be done to get delta for users in a group with group id equal to .
Thanks

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#odata-query-parameters

Could you clarify what you need? Do you need to find you why your two queries do not work or you need to get delta for users in a group?

i need to get delta for users in a group- as part of that i want to fetch all the properties without having to a do additional queries.

@enigmatic any update on the issue?


Note that: Delta queries are supported for groups, users, group memberships, and some other resources. However, member properties (like jobTitle,  mobilePhone, etc.) cannot be fetched in delta queries for groups.


When querying groups, you can track changes to membership, but detailed member properties are not provided in the same query.
You can use the $expand=members or $select=members in a delta query to track changes in group memberships (such as when users are added or removed).

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id+eq+'GroupId'&$select=members

Request Headers

prefer: return=minimal


Hence to get user-specific property changes (like jobTitle, mobilePhone, etc.),  you would need to run a separate user  query for that specific user.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID?$select=displayName,jobTitle,mobilePhone


To get users delta. make use of separate user delta query.
Reference:
group: delta - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
